# Sprite Kit Creating Selection Menu

Tags: sprite-kit

i have just finished implementing core functionality in my sprite kit tower defence game, and now am trying to refine the game. Firstly, i was thinking of doing a selection menu to select which tower to place. This is done in games such as Kingdom Rush where you can select between 4 different towers. However, i am kinda lost as to how to do this.

http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ihc4G76jA_Q/0.jpg // image of tower selection

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you want, I've never played the game you mentioned. Is it a situation where you tap a location to build a tower, which then brings up a small menu with a selection of towers to build? If that is the case then you can just make the first touch check if the touch location was in a tower "plot", and if so then open up a sub-menu sprite with the tower type buttons as children added to that sprite. The next touch would detect which of the four tower types in the menu was touched. If my description matches what you wan't just say and I'll add some code for you.

Comment: @AndyHeard wow, absolutely spot on! and thanks for you answer :)

Comment: @AndyHeard oh and your description matches exactly what i am talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As promised, heres a little code to get you going, I don't have my mac available to me at the moment so there may be a couple of typos but the concept is there:

Start out by defining which areas on your map are able to hold towers, this can be done in a few ways but as it's SpriteKit I'll use a sprite called `towerPlot` to represent an area that can take a tower.

Define a method to add a plot to a location with something like:

```
-(void)addTowerPlotAt:(CGPoint)location{
    SKSpriteNode* plot = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: "@plotImage";
    plot.location = location;
    plot.name = @"towerPlot";
    plot.zPosition = 1;  //if needed
    [self addChild: plot];
}
```

And your viewDidLoad method add something like:

```
[self addTowerPlotAt:CGPointMake(someX, someY)];
[self addTowerPlotAt:CGPointMake(otherX, otherY)];
```

In order to add your plots in the correct positions.

Next up is to check whether a touch was located on a plot;

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    //if the node is a plot, bring up the menu
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"towerPlot"]) {
        //add the menu frame
        SKSpriteNode* towerMenu = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: "@TowerMenu";
        towerMenu.position = node.position;

        SKSpriteNode* towerType1= [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: "@Tower1";
        towerType1.position = CGPointMake(someX, someY); /* remember this is relative to the menu, the next tower type has an example */
        towerType1.name = @"towerType1";
        [towerMenu addChild:towerType1];

        SKSpriteNode* towerType2= [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: "@Tower2";
        towerType2.position = CGPointMake((towerType2.size.width/2)-(towerMenu.size.width/2), 0); /* would add it to to the middle left of the menu */
        towerType1.name = @"towerType2";
        [towerMenu addChild:towerType2];

        //add and position as many tower types as you need
        [self addChild: towerMenu];
    }

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"towerType1"]) {
        //code to build the tower here
    }
}
```

There are other little bits you would need such as removing the menu after selecting a tower and ensuring that a tap returns a nodes name if they are layered oddly, but that's the gist of it I think.